# Facebook Graph API - can't access insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to connect our klipfolio dashboard with the facebook graph api. The problem is that somehow the facebook documentation does not seem to comply with the actual statement needed in order to return any results.

Here ist my statement according to facebook: [FB-Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/insights#page-post-impressions)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{mySite-ID}/insights?metric=(post_impressions_paid,post_impressions_organic)
```

The Error Message I receive when trying to execute this statement either with klipfolio or via the facbeook graph api explorer ist

> {
> "error": {
> "message": "(#100) The value must be a valid insights metric",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 100,
> }
> }

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Greetings from Vienna,

Christian

PD: be kind, I'm both new to this forum and also no developer ;)

Comment: Wrong syntax, it needs to be `insights?metric=post_impressions_paid,post_impressions_organic`

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thank you for your help.
No I get a permission denied message: do you know how to add the page access token correctly to the syntax?


```Service responded with exception status (400): {"error":{"message":"(#190) This method must be called with a Page Access Token","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"..."}}
```

Thank you a lot!
christian

Comment: GET parameter named `access_token`

Comment: hi, i'm sorry to bother you @CBroe, but how is the complete syntax?
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{mySite-ID}/insights?metric=post_impressions_paid,post_impressions_organic -> but where do  add the token in this syntax?

Comment: You add `&access_token=…` at the end - just the way GET parameters generally work.

Comment: thank you so much for your help . dunno what i'm doing wrong. keep getting the same error message (use page access token). although i'm using the page access token for the site i'm managing and using the syntax u told me @CBroe ‍♂️

Comment: Then your page access token probably _isn’t_ actually a page access token … (Just tested it, with a user access token I am getting that same error message, whereas when I use a page access token, it works fine.)

Comment: I used this code to create my page access token 
```https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/accounts?
  fields=name,access_token&
  access_token={user-accesss-token}```

then i've used the resulting access token. 

don't know what I should do differently.

do you see any error @CBroe

Comment: What permissions does the user token you used for this encompass? What is the user’s role on the page in question?

Comment: the permissions i've added are the following: 
read_insights, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, read_page_mailboxes, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info, leads_retrieval, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement, public_profile

Comment: i'm the admin of the page

Comment: and @CBroe: thank you sooooo much for getting back to me so fast!!!!!

Comment: Input the token into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/, and see what that has to say.

Comment: i've the info from above from this debugger

Comment: I meant regarding what type of token it is, whether data access might have expired, what it has to say in the “Granular Scopes” section, etc.

Comment: type: page; it expires in around 1h; dataaccess expires in 3 month; granular scope is eather "Applies to all objects" or specific to my site

Comment: What happens when you test that same request with that same token in Graph API Explorer?

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: Then I’d suggest you file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs For me this works perfectly fine.

Comment: ok. thank you soo much for your help!!!